# XSL Parameter Value is not Inserted into Database while removing namespace from XML file

Tags: xslt

I have a following xml file .

T0020.xml

SAFER
04.02


01.00
REPLACE
2009-09-01T00:00:00
CT


274845
US
AR
55002
I
100
2007-11-06
2009-08-03

I have to insert xml data into following table

IRP_ACCOUNT

### Field Name           Field Type

FILE_NAME             VARCHAR2(120) 
IRP_ACCOUNT_NUMBER     VARCHAR2(32) 
IRP_ACCOUNT_TYPE       VARCHAR2(1) 
IRP_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(12) 
IRP_BASE_COUNTRY       VARCHAR2(12) 
IRP_BASE_STATE         VARCHAR2(12) 
IRP_STATUS_CODE        VARCHAR2(12) 
IRP_STATUS_DATE        VARCHAR2(10) 
IRP_UPDATE_DATE        VARCHAR2(10)

My code to insert xml Data into Database is ...

OracleXMLSave oracleXMLSave =new OracleXMLSave(conn, tableNamePro);

```
    //set XSL file.
    File xslFileName = new File(CviewFileReader.readFileFromClassPathAsURL(xslFolderLocation + "/" + rootNode.trim() + "/" + xslFileNamePro.trim() + ".xsl").getFile().substring(1).replace("%20", " "));
    Reader xsltReader=new FileReader(xslFileName);
    oracleXMLSave.setXSLT(xsltReader, null);

    //set fileNameParameterValueIn XLS file. so this value insert into database table as "FILE_VALUE" field.
    oracleXMLSave.setXSLTParam("FILE_NAME", "'" + onlyXMLfileName + "'");

    //set row separter value.
    oracleXMLSave.setRowTag(xmlRowTagVal);

    //set ignoreCase to true.
    oracleXMLSave.setIgnoreCase(true);        

     //give here XML file path
     FileInputStream xmlFileNameForInserting = new FileInputStream(xmlFileName.getAbsoluteFile());
     oracleXMLSave.insertXML(xmlFileNameForInserting);
```

My XSLT File for Inserting Data is ...

When applying this xslt to insert to Database only FILE_NAME value which has been passed through xslt parameter is not inserted into Database.

See below all value are inserted except FILE_NAME.

FILE_NAME IRP_ACCOUNT_NUMBER IRP_ACCOUNT_TYPE IRP_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER IRP_BASE_COUNTRY IRP_BASE_STATE IRP_STATUS_CODE IRP_STATUS_DATE IRP_UPDATE_DATE

---

55002 I 274845 US AR 100 2007-11-06 2009-08-03

I have stuck on this point Pls help me....still any confusion then let me know...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What language? Can you show sample XML? Sample code that does the transformation?

Comment: <T0019 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.safersys.org/namespaces/T0019V1 T0019V1.xsd" xmlns="http://www.safersys.org/namespaces/T0019V1"> 
<IFTA_ACCOUNT> 
<IFTA_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER>4</IFTA_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER> 
<IFTA_NAME> <NAME_TYPE>LG</NAME_TYPE> <NAME>AAA COOPER TRANSPORTATION</NAME> 
<IFTA_ADDRESS> <ADDRESS_TYPE>PH</ADDRESS_TYPE> <STREET_LINE_1>1751 KINSEY RD</STREET_LINE_1> <CITY>DOTHAN</CITY> <STATE>AL</STATE> <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY> </IFTA_ADDRESS> 
</IFTA_NAME> </IFTA_ACCOUNT>
</T0019>

This is a sample xml ..and...

Comment: i am builing application in java in which i want to transfer this xml data to following table using above xslt  but the problem is that data is inserted to Database but File Name value is not inserting to Db 

FILE_NAME                               VARCHAR2(120) 
IFTA_CARRIER_ID_NUMBER                  VARCHAR2(12)

in which FILE_Name is coming from Parameter value ...
Pls help me Thank in advance ...

Comment: any body can help me ...i am stuck on this point...

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you put the `<xsl:element>` part? Did you declare `<xsl:param name="FILE" />` in your stylesheet?

Comment: ya following declaration i have made 
<xsl:param name="FILE_NAME" select="T0019/IFTA_ACCOUNT/FILE_NAME" />
above  <xsl:template match="/"> .

Comment: <xsl:param name="FILE_NAME" select="T0020/IRP_ACCOUNT/FILE_NAME" value=""/>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="T0020">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="* | T0020/IRP_ACCOUNT"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="@* | text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
     <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: <xsl:template match="T0020/IRP_ACCOUNT">
 
       <xsl:element name="IRP_ACCOUNT">

          <xsl:element name="FILE_NAME">
               <xsl:value-of select="$FILE_NAME"/>
          </xsl:element>

          <xsl:element name="IRP_BASE_STATE">
               <xsl:value-of select="IRP_BASE_STATE"/>
          </xsl:element>
   ....
   .....
   .....
</xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: But what is `T0020` supposed to match in your sample document, to begin with?

Comment: Pls dont consider T0020 xslt statment,i have mistakenly paste it..my xslt i have pasted in my question pls consider that...Sorry for wrong posting bcoz of first time on this ...

Comment: Michael Can i provide u detail of Question if u didn't get that one ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, the best you can do is state in details what is your input (minimal, but complete, both sample xml and xsl), what is expected output, etc.

Comment: I have posted same question on below link Please check this link as i am unable to edit my question properly.

http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/77578-xslt-parameter-value-not-inserted-into-database.html#post251473

I will be waiting for your reply..